# Discord.js Bot settings when changed on one server changes on all of them running it on repl.it

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Hi so there really isn't much to the problem above I just need to know how to separate the settings on one server from the settings on another server.
Here is the code I am currently using!

```
client.on('message', (msg) => {
if (msg.content == `${prefix}setup`) {
    msg.channel.send('To set the prefix use !prefix set (the prefix)');
    msg.channel.send('To set the code prefix use !prefix code (the prefix preferably your yt name)');
    msg.channel.send('Make sure to set the channel for early code release/access use !early set (id of the channel)');
  } else if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}prefix set`)) {
    prefix = msg.content.replace(`${prefix}prefix set`, '').trim()
    console.log(prefix)
    msg.channel.send('Prefix Changed!')
  } else if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}prefix code`)) {
    name = msg.content.replace(`${prefix}prefix code`, '').trim()
    console.log(name)
    client.channels.cache.get(early).send(`Prefix set to ${name}`)
    code = `New code is ${name}${Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)}`
    client.channels.cache.get(early).send(`${code}`);
  } else if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}early set`)) {
    early = msg.content.replace(`${prefix}early set`, '').trim()
    console.log(early)
    msg.channel.send('Early Channel Changed!')
  } else if (msg.content == `${prefix}new code`) {
    code = `code is ${name}${Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)}`
    msg.channel.send(`New ${code}`)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a database for individual server settings. Thankfully, this is very easy to do. You can use [`discord-prefix`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-prefix).

---

### Discord Prefix

Discord Prefix is a simple Node.js module that lets you efficiently manage custom prefixes for your discord bot

#### Install

```
npm i discord-prefix
```

#### Github

[RedLukeBug/discord-prefix](https://github.com/RedLukeBug/discord-prefix)

---

**Hoped this helped!**